# How to evaluate $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} n\int_{[0,1]}f(x)e^{-nx}dx$

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous. How do I compute the following limits?

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{[0,1]}f(x)e^{-nx}dx$

and

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} n\int_{[0,1]}f(x)e^{-nx}dx$

So, i the second limit it seems that the fact $f$ is continuous at $0$ will be very important. I've started this problem by considering the special case where there exists $\delta > 0$ such $f$ is constant on $[0,\delta]$. I've been trying to work on this problem for awhile now and am starting to get tunnel vision, I would appreciate some fresh insights! Thanks!

Comment: Interesting problem!

Comment: I think the first one can be handled with the dominated convergence theorem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $u=nx$. Then, provided everything is well behaved ($f$ having no $n$ dependence for example) we can use dominated convergence

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_0^n f\left(\frac{u}{n}\right)e^{-u}du = f(0)\int_0^\infty e^{-u}du = f(0)$$

Comment: Thanks. What exactly is the dominating function here? And as $n \rightarrow \infty$ we have $\frac{u}{n} \rightarrow 0$? I'm not used to seeing $u$ substitution with Lebesgue integrals, it makes me nervous!!

Comment: @MathematicalMushroom we make the case that if $|f(x)| \leq M$ then $\int_0^n |f\left(\frac{u}{n}\right) e^{-u}|du \leq \int_0^\infty M e^{-u}du$. In two steps we bound the integral on the interval $[0,n]$ by a different integral on $[0,\infty]$, which then has the dominating function $Me^{-u}$ on the new interval. This guy is in part one of many sequences of functions that converge to the Dirac delta (although this limit is one sided so it has to be modified).

Answer (score 1):

For the  first one:

$\frac{1}{e^{nx}} \leq 1,\forall n \in \Bbb{N}$  and since $f$ is continuous on a compact intervals then it is bounded by some $M>0$

So $|f(x)e^{-nx}| \leq M \in L^1[0,1]$

Thus by Dominated convergence we have that the limit is zero.

In the second do the substitution $x=t/n$ and exploit the continuity of $f$ along with Dominated convergence.

Comment: Does $\frac{1}{e^{nx}} \leq 1$ still hold when $x$ is really close to zero??

Comment: @MathematicalMushroom yes it does

Answer (score 1):

There are $\xi_n\in[0,\sqrt{n}]$ and $\nu_n\in[\sqrt{n},n]$, s.t.
\begin{align*}
n\int_0^1f(x)e^{-nx}\mathrm{d}x&=\int_0^nf\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)e^{-x}\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_0^{\sqrt{n}}f\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)e^{-x}\mathrm{d}x+
\int_{\sqrt{n}}^nf\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)e^{-x}\mathrm{d}x\\
&=f\left(\frac{\xi_n}{n}\right)\int_0^{\sqrt{n}}e^{-x}\mathrm{d}x+f\left(\frac{\nu_n}{n}\right)\int_{\sqrt{n}}^ne^{-x}\mathrm{d}x.
\end{align*}
In this form, the rest should be easy to calculate.